# batchUpdate using pdo and MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

```
function loopFunction(PDO $pdo, $products) {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    foreach($products as $uid => $element) {
        $isPremium = $element[0] != false && in_array('isPremium', $element[0]) ? 1 : 0;
        $isExclusive = $element[0] != false && in_array('isExclusive', $element[0]) ? 1 : 0;
        $isLimited = $element[0] != false && in_array('isLimited', $element[0]) ? 1 : 0;
        $IsNew = $element[0] != false && in_array('IsNew', $element[0]) ? 1 : 0;
        $DirectCallId = isset($element[1]) ? $element[1] : false;

        insertOrUpdate($pdo, $isPremium, $isExclusive, $isLimited, $IsNew, $DirectCallId, $uid);
    }
    

    $pdo->commit();
}

function insertOrUpdate(PDO $pdo, $isPremium, $isExclusive, $isLimited, $IsNew, $DirectCallId, $uid) {

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberRows FROM [PaynowCom].[DirectCall].[Report] WHERE ReportId = (:value1)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value1', $DirectCallId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = (int)$stmt->fetchColumn();

    if ($count) {
        $sql2 = "UPDATE TOP(1) [PaynowCom].[DirectCall].[Report]
        SET isPremium = (:value1), isExclusive= (:value2), isLimited = (:value3), IsNew = (:value4)
        WHERE reportId = (:value5)";
        $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
        
        $stmt2->bindParam(':value1', $isPremium);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':value2', $isExclusive);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':value3', $isLimited);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':value4', $IsNew);

        $stmt2->bindParam(':value5', $DirectCallId);
        if (!$stmt2->execute()) {
            print_r('error');
        }
    } else {
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO [PaynowCom].[DirectCall].[Report] 
        (created, reportId, uid, isPremium, isExclusive, isLimited, IsNew)
        VALUES (getdate(), :value1, :value2, :value3, :value4, :value5, :value6)";

        $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
        
        $stmt2->bindParam(':value1', $DirectCallId);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':value2', $uid);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':value3', $isPremium);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':value4', $isExclusive);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':value5', $isLimited);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':value6', $IsNew);

        if (!$stmt2->execute()) {
            print_r('error');
        }
    }
```

I think this can be improved a lot, but I am more concerned about how the transaction would work, because I am doing a conditional insert inside the code and I am wondering if the transaction would work as expected since we have multiple MSSQL prepared statements and not just 1 for each element.

I think the insert or update could be improved and we could use something else, but I am more preoccupied with the transaction and how it works with pdo.

I heard that conditional insert can cause duplicate keys or deadlocks, but I am not too sure about that.

Comment: Why are you using a transaction here? In what way do the rows, you update or insert, depend upon each other?

Comment: I was wondering about that, because initially I wanted to do a batch insert and it made sense to do it in a transaction to reduce the number of calls, but now that I am making several calls and I do a check with if, I am not sure if it would work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

When you attempt to UPDATE the "first" row of a result set without using an ORDER BY clause in the SELECT, there is no guarantee that you are *actually* affecting the latest entry.  [Is it safe to use LIMIT without ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34812412/2943403)

I don't personally have any experience with MSSQL yet, but I think you should definitely read and absorb the insights at [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/108403/2943403) to understand the options and concerns when doing an "upsert".

Using a transaction is probably better intentioned when you implement it within your `insertOrUpdate()` function.

Your function naming is way too vague to be helpful/searchable within your project.  Without knowing more context, I might suggest `batchSaveProductPermissions()`. I also find `$element` to be an unhelpful name for what I am interpreting as a "row" that contains "permission details".  Since you are only accessing the first two elements of the row, you can even try "array destucturing" syntax inside the foreach if you like.

I see individual variable assignments in your foreach loop, but several of those variables seem to be logically related/group-able since they relate to permission values.  I might package the permissions and the directCallId as an associative array before passing it into `insertOrUpdate()`.  This will reduce some horizontal bloat and simplify maintenance when you need to extend the permission options in the future. ([Generalized Demo](https://3v4l.org/FLIip)) You can use null coalescing to replace `isset() ? :` syntax. I recommend not juggling different names for the same data; align `$DirectCallId` with your database's `reportId`.

```
function batchSaveProductPermissions(PDO $pdo, array $products): void {
    $allPermissions = ['isPremium', 'isExclusive', 'isLimited', 'IsNew'];
    $defaultPermissions = array_fill_keys($allPermissions, 0);

    foreach ($products as $uid => [$permissions, $directCallId]) {
        $payload = array_fill_keys(
            array_intersect($allPermissions, $permissions),
            1
         )
         + $defaultPermissions
         + ['reportId' => $directCallId ?? false];    
        insertOrUpdate($pdo, $uid, $payload);
    }
}
```

Now your receiving function can begin like this:

```
function insertOrUpdate(PDO $pdo, int $uid, array $payload):void {
```

Then within your `insertOrUpdate()` function, you can leverage the beauty of the associative payload to avoid writing those vague `:value#` placeholders -- now you can use very clear placeholder names.  You can even skip those `bindParam()` calls by directly feeding an associative array into the `execute()` calls.  (Some minor manipulations to the arrays will be required depending on the query.)

To avoid `get_date()` in your INSERT queries, apply the DEFAULT value on insertion to be the current date and let your database handle this automatically.

As a general rule, I prefer to `return` the affected row count from UPDATE functions and `return` the insertId from INSERT functions.  In this case, you will expect to affect, at most, one row, so I'd probably return the `id` of the inserted/affected row.  I realize that your code isn't currently interested in this return value, but I find that it helps with debugging if this technique is already in place.

Finally, do not `print` errors from a querying function.  You can throw and catch exceptions if you like, but avoid expressly printing from within the function body.

Comment: I need to catch a concern in my own scripting.  Might your `$products` array possibly have a row that doesn't have a second element (`$element[1]`)?  If this is possible, then my array destructuring technique is ill-suited.  @Sayaman